# How to conditionally change bar colour in chart (VBA)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop

I have a series of cash flows that I want to chart on a 3D bar chart.
I set the data source of the chart to the range of cells that contain the cash flows from Yr 0 to Yr 7.

However, i want to change the color of the bar according to whether cash flow is negative or not.

I was thinking of using For Each loop and If/Else to do that but I have no idea how to refer to the value of each bar. Please help.

I have cash flow for e.g. -1000, 100, 500, 650, 300, 400, 200
and I have the following code:

```
Dim j As Integer
Dim cell As Range
Dim flows As Range
Set flows = Worksheets("Data Input").Range("B2:B8")

For Each cell In flows
    For j = 1 To 7
        If cell.Value < 0 Then
            Worksheets("Output").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(j).Select
            With Selection.Format.Fill
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End With
        ElseIf cell.Value > 0 Then
            Worksheets("Output").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(j).Select
            With Selection.Format.Fill
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            End With
        End If
    Next j
Next cell
```

What should happen is the first bar turns red because cash flow is negative and the rest should turn green.
The code runs but the bars are still default blue...

Comment: https://peltiertech.com/conditional-formatting-of-excel-charts/

Comment: I don't understand why this question was judged "too broad".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Developer's tab, simply "Record Macro" and create your desired bar chart. After formatting to your liking, "Stop Recording" and then review the code. This is the easiest way to start.

Let's assume you recorded the macro. During the recording, look for the point where you colored one of the bars red for < 0 value.

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(3).Select
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0 0)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
```

The code selects something called points. So, we wish to find out what this means.

> Object Browser [F2] within the Visual Basic Editor [F11] for additional details on objects.

Looking in the object browser it says that points is a collection of objects, and a member of **Excel.Series** (which now becomes the point of interest). Browsing through the other members of the Series object, we fined **Values**... Putting this knowledge together:

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim chart As Excel.chart
Dim series As Excel.series
Dim i As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")
Set chart = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1").chart
Set series = chart.FullSeriesCollection(1)

For i = 1 To series.Points.Count
    If (series.Values(i) < 0) Then
        chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
Next i
```